# Increase and fix the point highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with the chart!
How can I enlarge and fixed the point I clicked on?
An example of my chart below, I will be grateful for the help
example: http://jsfiddle.net/4bounhdg/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 6}, 
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            for (var i = 0; i < this.series.data.length; i++) {
                                this.series.data[i].update({ color: '#7db7ed' }, true, false);
                            }
                            this.update({ color: '#0053ff'}, true, false);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0]        
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the higher radius in the update callback.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rkqtcps8/

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function() {

      this.update({
        color: '#0053ff',
        marker: {
            radius: 20
        }
      }, true, false);
    }
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update